# Alterar o id de um elemento

Tags: javascript

Criei uma tabela com botões onde cada um recebe um id diferente, todos tem o mesmo prefixo mudando apenas o final, que vai de 0 a 99.

```js
const cellArray = []
let cellWidth = 10
let cellHeight = 10
var isClicked = false

function start() {
    createCellsDataStructure()
    renderCells()
}

function createCellsDataStructure() {
    const numberOfCells = cellWidth * cellHeight

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
        cellArray[i] = 0
    }
}

function cellsProgation() {

}

function changeColor(element){
    var id = element.id

    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "purple"

    neighbor(id)
}

function neighbor(id) {
    document.getElementById(id-11).style.background = "#999"
    document.getElementById(id-10).style.background = "#999"
    document.getElementById(id-9).style.background = "#999"
    document.getElementById(id-1).style.background = "#999"
    //document.getElementById(id+1).style.background = "#999"
    //document.getElementById(id+9).style.background = "#999"
    //document.getElementById(id+10).style.background = "#999"
    //document.getElementById(id+11).style.background = "#999"
    
}

function renderCells() {
    let html = '<table cellpadding=0 cellsapcing=0>'
    for (let row = 0; row < cellHeight; row++) {
        html += '<tr>'
        
        for (let column = 0; column < cellWidth; column++) {
            var cellIndex = column + (cellWidth * row)
            html += '<td class="cell-index">'
            html += `<button id="${cellIndex}" onClick="changeColor(this)"></button>`
            html += '</td>'
        }


        html += '</tr>'
    }
    html += '</table>'

    document.querySelector('#cellBlock').innerHTML = html
}


start()
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fundamento de Sistemas</title>
    <style>
        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 18px;
            position: relative;
        }

        button {
            font-size: 10px;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="cellBlock"></div>
    <script src="constructor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Na função `neighbor()` quero pegar o index do botão clicado e alterá-lo de forma que possa, através deste, saber o index dos botões ao seu redor.

Ex: Quando clicar no botão 55, os vizinhos (44, 45, 46, 54, 56, 64, 65, 66) devem alterar sua cor. Consegui fazer de um jeito que as posições anteriores ao botão eu consigo alterar, no caso do exemplo acima do 44 ao 54, mas os posteriores eu não consigo, pois ao invés de somar os valores ele está apenas concatenando os valores, exemplo, 55 + 1 retorna 551, e não 56.

Aparte comentada de `neighbor()` é a que está dando erro.

Comment: Você poderia colocar a função aqui para vermos como está até o momento

Comment: Ainda está com o problema? Id é uma propriedade do HTML, e HTML não consegue distinguir texto de números. Como resultado, quando você pega o id de um elemento ele vem como string e você sabe o que acontece quando utilizamos `+` com uma string. Tente utilizar `id = parseInt(id)` bem no início da função `neighbor`.

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaannnnnnoooooo!!!
Muito obg, deu certo agr, vlw msm!!

Comment: @user140828 passa teu comentário pra resposta pra mim colocar como respondida, vlw pela ajuda mano...

Answer (score 0):

Usando o jQuery seria algo assim:

```
//Crio a função recebendo o elemento
function cellNeighbor(this) {
  //Pego o valor do atributo id
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  //Separo a para poder pegar o id, criando um array de string de duas posições
  id = id.split("index-$");
  //Como era um array de string finalmente pego o numero
  id = id[1];
  //Crio os ids dos vizinhos pelo id atual (essa logica pode ser melhorada, foi o 
  //mais fácil que pensei na hora)
  if(id > 3)
    let neighborButtons = [id-4, id-3, id-2, id-1, id+1, id+2, id+3, id+4];
  else
    let neighborButtons = [id+1, id+2, id+3, id+4]; 
  //Crio o for para setar a cor de cada um dos vizinhos
  for(let i=0; i < 8; i++) {
    $("#cell-index-$" + neighborButtons[i]).css("atributo", "valor");
  }
}
```